# Storing reference to setTimeout() dynamically

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm creating a reusable function to monitor how frequently  a button is clicked and wait until the user stops clicking it to continue and it seemed to work great until i tried creating 2 buttons (which will be how it will be in production)

I am using objects to store the data while the user is clicking.
If the timer is not reset and runs out, it will post the data.

If you try just spamming the lemon button a few times you will see how it works. The same if you spam the diamond button.

```js
var arr = {};
var SC={}; 

function SpamControl(u, i) {
 this.ui = u+i;
  this.Sp = SC[ui];


if (!SC[ui]){

  SC[ui] = arr;
  SC[ui].timer= "";
  SC[ui].count = 0;
 }
   clearTimeout(SC[ui].timer);
   SC[ui].count = SC[ui].count + 1; 
   SC[ui].timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#count').prepend(u+" gave "+ SC[ui].count +" "+i+"'s in a controlled fashion!<br>");
         delete SC[ui];
    }, 1000);  
}
```

The problem comes when you spam between the two buttons. I had hoped it would handle the two users attached to the buttons separately but it seems not and im not sure why.

I realize this is a bit unclear but all i can say is try it out to understand what i mean

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gbe7dv1r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use global variables, use local ones:

```
  let ui = u + i;
  let Sp = SC[ui];
```

Also all entries in `Sp` will reference the same `arr` object, when initualizing an entry you might want to create a new object for each:

```
 SC[ui] = { };
```

Finally some wise words: Cryptic abbreviations like u, i, ui, SC, Sp, arr will really cause you headaches when maintaining this piece of code.

```
 const controls = { /*[name]: { timer, count } */ }; 

 function spamControl(user, item) {
  const name = user + item;
  const control = controls[name] || (controls[name] = { timer: 0, count: 0 });

  control.count += 1;

  clearTimeout(control.timer);
  control.timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
      $('#count').prepend(
        `${user} gave ${control.count} ${item}"s in a controlled fashion!<br>`
      );
     delete controls[name];
  }, 1000);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonas Wilms to this perfect answer. I never had any formal training and tend to make these kind of mistakes. Your code is so clean, I will study it and learn from your corrections. Thanks for the time and the tips!

Comment: Oh well, I never had any "formal training" (apart of some Java at school) as well ... just keep writing code, it's just a matter of time (and a bit of talent)

Comment: Just one thing, I would love it if you could explain to me why my code didn't work? was it overwriting the individual objects? if so how or why? Thanks